# Solving the Helmholtz equation numerically

Tags: finite-difference, helmholtz-equation

I am trying to solve the Helmholtz equation in some complex unbounded 2D domain:

$$\left( \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2} + E \right) u(x, y) = 0$$

However, to start with, I tried doing that in the simplified domain $\Omega = [-\infty, \infty] \times [0, H]$, that is, just a tube, with Dirichlet boundary conditions on the walls: $\psi(x, 0) = 0, \psi(x, H) = 0$.

It is known that solutions of this problem are of form:

$$\psi_{n \rightarrow}(x, y) = \sin(\frac{\pi n}{H} y) e^{i \sqrt{E - (\pi n / H)^2} x}$$

$$\psi_{n \leftarrow}(x, y) = \sin(\frac{\pi n}{H} y) e^{-i \sqrt{E - (\pi n / H)^2} x}$$

, for $n = 1 \dots \infty$.

To solve numerically, I have to bound the domain somehow, so I restricted it to $[0, L] \times [0, H]$ for some big $L$.

We want the solution to be unique up to normalization, I am doing that by:

- assuming $\left( \frac{\pi}{H} \right)^2 < E < \left( \frac{2 \pi}{H} \right)^2$, that is, getting solution of form $A \psi_{1 \rightarrow}(x, y) + B \psi_{1 \leftarrow}(x, y)$
- getting rid of the $B$ coefficient and using the following ansatz in the asymptotic region $x \le 0$: $\psi(x, y) = A \sin(\frac{\pi}{H}y) \sqrt{E - \pi^2/H^2} x)$

So now we should get the solution $\psi_{1 \rightarrow}(x, y) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{H}y) \sqrt{E - \pi^2/H^2} x)$ up to the normalization after solving numerically.

I am substituting the ansatz, getting boundary conditions:

- $\psi(0, y) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{H}y)$, (no $x$ dependency due to the freedom in normalization)
- $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}(0, y) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{H}y) i \sqrt{E - \pi^2/H^2}$

Next, to solve using finite differences, I used the grid (I will assume cell size is equal to $1$ for simplicity), so $\psi_{n, m}$ now approximates $\psi(n, m)$, and the central differences scheme, rewriting the equation as:

$$\psi_{n, m + 1} + \psi_{n + 1, m} + \psi_{n, m - 1} + \psi_{n - 1, m} - 4 \psi_{n, m} + E \psi_{n, m} = 0$$

I know the values of two first columns of the grid from my boundary conditions:

$$\psi_{0, m} = \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{H}y \right)$$

$$\psi_{1, m} = \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{H}y \right) e^{i \sqrt{E - \pi^2/H^2}}$$

Now that we have two consecutive columns $n - 2$, $n - 1$, we should be able to obtain all the columns up to  $L$, since:

$$\psi_{n, m} = 4 \psi_{n - 1, m} - E \psi_{n - 1, m} - \psi_{n - 2, m} - \psi_{n - 1, m - 1} - \psi_{n - 1, m + 1}$$

However, for some reason, this computation diverges and grows exponentially as $n$ goes from $0$ to $L$. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong (wrong boundary conditions, or I shouldn't use central differences), or that should work?

P.S. I tried the same for 1D Helmholtz in the domain $[-\infty, \infty]$ and $\psi$ diverges as well in this case, so it does seem as I am missing something fundamental.

P.P.S. Turns out that I was just using large step size in the 1D case. However, setting step sizes smaller and smaller in the 2D case does not help :(

Comment: The Cauchy problem for elliptic PDEs is ill-posed because it is not stable w.r.t. the data.

Comment: @HuiZhang Thanks! How should I approach this kind of problem then? I googled something about "artificial" and "transparent" boundary conditions, and it looks somewhat complicated, are these artificial potentials inevitable, or there are simplex methods of solving that?

Comment: Not sure what boundary conditions at $\pm\infty$ do you want? Sommerfeld radiation? Where the known data are given? At some boundary or interior sources?

Comment: @HuiZhang I want my solution to represent a wave scattered from the left side of the waveguide

Comment: You need an artificial outgoing boundary condition at the right side. It is usually $(\partial_x-i\sqrt{E})\psi=0.$ But if you know the mode at the right side as $sin(\pi y/H)exp(i\sqrt{E-\pi^2/H^2}x)$ you can use $(\partial_x-i\sqrt{E-\pi^2/H^2})\psi=0.$ (But if you have the analytical solution, why do you want to solve it numerically?)

Comment: @HuiZhang oh, I tried the same, but forgot about $i$ and was using $(\partial_x - \sqrt{E - \frac{\pi^2}{H^2}}) \psi = 0$, which resulted in an incorrect solution. Now that I fixed it, it seems to work fine. Thanks!
About why solving numerically if I know analytic solution: I want actually to solve the problem for some complex domain with resonators and stuff, I was solving this just to warm up, since I'm not very good at numerical methods.

Comment: @HuiZhang also: what boundary condition should I impose on the left? First I wanted to impose the same radiation condition, but this does not result in a unique solution, since any scalar multiple of a solution would satisfy the equation, radiating conditions on the left and right, and Dirichlet condition on the walls. I tried then just setting $\psi(0, y) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{H} y)$, that is, fixing the constant coefficient of the solution, and it does seem to give the correct result. Is that a correct way of handling uniqueness?

Comment: What `correct result` do you expect? The boundary condition at the left side can be $(-\partial_x+i\sqrt{E-\pi^2/H^2}x)(\psi-\psi_{\mathrm{incoming}})=0,$ where $\psi_{\mathrm{incoming}}$ is the known incoming wave travelling from the left to the right.

Comment: @HuiZhang I expect to get the answer of the form $\psi(x, y) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{H} y) e^{i \sqrt{E - \pi^2 / H^2} x}$. Yeah, this boundary condition seems to be the condition I need, thanks a lot!

Comment: @HuiZhang I'd also accept if you post these formulas as an answer